# Icon Fonts in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, icon-fonts

I don't use Font Awesome but I do use icon fonts in the way described by Chris Coyier on CSS Tricks.

I wish to tweak his code to enable them to work in IE7. I realise generated content is not supported in IE7 so I had a look at how Font Awesome deals with the issue and it looks like they use this JS expression:

```
.ie7icon(@inner) {
  *zoom: ~"expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '@{inner}')";
}
```

My problem is that I just can;t get my head around what it is actually doing. I need to know this so I can tweak it and make it work for the way I am using icons.

ADDED:

I have this in my Sass file at the moment:

```
[data-icon]:before {
  @extend %icon-font
  content: attr(data-icon)
  speak: none
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
```

1. How could I use the JS expression to add IE7 support on?  Maybe a mixin would help here somehow?
2. Can you explain the actual JS expression?

Comment: There are 2 parts to the code you've pasted.  First, it is a LESS mixin.  Second, it is using some IE proprietary CSS to invoke JavaScript.  Now which portion don't you understand?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was a LESS mixin. I use Sass so I didn't pick up on the LESS syntax for mixins.  I'll post some more stuff in my OP - Added

Answer (score 7):

The Sass equivalent of that mixin would be like this:

```
@mixin ie7icon($inner) {
    *zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '#{$inner}');
}

.foo {
    @include ie7icon(\f000);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  *zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '\f000');
}
```

Zoom is a proprietary IE CSS property and tends to be the property of choice for triggering *HasLayout* (see: http://haslayout.net/haslayout) because it doesn't have any side effects for non-IE browsers.

The asterisk before the `zoom` property is your standard *star hack*.  It exploits a bug in the CSS parser for IE<8 as a way to provide styles exclusively to those browsers (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack)

Expressions are primarily an IE only thing.  They allow you to run arbitrary JavaScript via CSS (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx).  This particular expression is setting the contents of whatever tag it is being applied to with the value of `$inner`, so it is really only intended to be used with an empty tag like so:

```
<p><i class="foo"></i> I have an icon!</p>
```

Comment: Perfect, Makes sense now. I'll try to build Sass mixin that should allow me to get icon fonts to work with IE fallbacks in standalone and with text situations - hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to covert your img to font formats, [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

and the css would like

```
@font-face { font-family: 'imgtoicon';
src:url('icons.eot');
src: url('icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('icons.svg#icons') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

create a class name for the font

```
.iconic {
display:inline-block;
font-family: 'imgtoicon';
font-weight: normal;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

icon references example

```
.cat:before{content:'\e011';}
.dog:before{content:'\e022';}
```

in your css for IE7

```
  .iconic {
        font-family: 'imgtoicon'; 
        font-weight: normal;
        }

    .cat{ *zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = "1", this.innerHTML = '\e011'); }
```

Comment: I understand how to use the fonts. It;s the actual javascript line I need explaining.

I have this in my SS at the moment:

    [data-icon]:before {
      @extend %icon-font;
      content: attr(data-icon);
      speak: none;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased

How could I use the JS expression to add IE7 support on?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an alternative stylesheet using a conditional like so (credits to [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)) `<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie7.css"  />< ![endif]-->`

Then in your ie7.css :

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  font-family: your-icon-font;
 } 
.icon-custom { *zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = "1", this.innerHTML = 'utf8-Custom'); }
```

I think *zoom helps giving a layout to the element and debug a IE+windows weird behavior, while this.innerHTML enables you to provide the utf8 value that corresponds to your icon.

You could also go like this (still [Paul Irish and h5bp](http://html5boilerplate.com/)) and alternatively give a specific class to your html selector by pasting this line below your DOCTYPE :

```
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

Then you can go

```
.lt-ie8 [class^="icon-"],
.lt-ie8 [class*=" icon-"] {
  font-family: your-icon-font;
 } 
.lt-ie8 .icon-custom { *zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = "1", this.innerHTML = 'utf8-Custom'); }
```

h5bp plans to drop support for IE6 IE7 and considers [complete removal for these conditionals][3] but I find them useful for this especially.

Hope this helps
Please let me know how it goes

Charles

Comment: Thanks, I haven't got a problem in how to target stuff to IE7 or other Ie versions. I have code in for that already.

My two issues now are:

1. Could I make the CSS I posted into a mixin with this IE JS expression a fallback?

2. How does the *zoom: part work? - I'm only asking this as I have never seen *zoom inside where the normal css properties go. Normally it is used as a selector?

Answer (score 0):

If your icon is not intented to change at runtime, you could use the following :

```
.icon-glass {
  *zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xf000;');
}
```

If your icon is intended to change at runtime, you could do something like this :

```
.icon-glass {
  *top:expression(0, this.innerHTML = '&#xf000;');
}
```

Unfortunately, this is extremely slow. While it is likely to work in IE6 with a significant reduction of your performance, IE7 is likely to crash if you have too many icons on your page. So I wouldn't recommend this second technique unless you use only very few icons and you can afford the performance reduction.